# Does GetConsumingEnumerable actually remove an item from a BlockingCollection?

Tags: c#, collections, blockingcollection

The MSDN remarks at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx state that...

"The default collection type for BlockingCollection is ConcurrentQueue"

Does this mean that while I am running "GetConsumingEnumerable()" on the collection, the item pulled is being dequeued from the queue and after use will be marked for GC?

In other words... In the following snippet,

```
foreach (var item in collection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            //do something with item
        }
```

what happens to item after the loop iteration?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The items will be removed from the collection, and if no other references to them exist they will be eligible for collection.

From the documentation of [GetConsumingEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx):

> Return Value
>   Type: `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`
>   **An `IEnumerable<T>` that removes and returns items from the collection.**

*(my emphasis)*

Comment: Ah, don't know how I missed that. Thanks!